# Loading text file via NodeJS and performing Regex doesn't work

Tags: node.js, regex, fs

Having a weird issue.

Trying to do Regex on a text file. The following matches strings with Slider text and some formatting.

`ListOfSliderStrings` returns a list when not using FS, as it should, and instead putting the document into a variable at the top of the document (just to test with).

Actually loading the document via FS readFileSync() (as below) does not.

Having said that, console logging the FS loaded document shows the correct data.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const yargs = require("yargs");

const options = yargs
    .usage("Usage: -f <file>")
    .option("f", { alias: "file", describe: "Your file", type: "string", demandOption: true })
    .argv;

let textfile = fs.readFileSync(options.file).toString();

console.log(textfile); // THIS PRINTS THE DOCUMENT, SO IT SEEMS IT IS BEING READ

let listOfSliderStrings = textfile.match(/(slider.*:.*\n)/g);
```

Where's the stupid mistake I'm making?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the unexpected behavior is, that you are experiencing.

Try reading in the text file with a string encoding.

```
let textfile = fs.readFileSync(options.file, 'utf-8').toString();
```

In order to use the `match` method of the string, you should see that `typeof(textfile)` is `string` (which supplying the second argument to `readFileSync` can do.

Comment: I've tried this as well, it's so weird... Note that it only occurs on a forEach that happens on listOfSliderStrings just after. listOfSliderStrings using FS returns NULL (like the RegEx is failing). I'm not null-checking the variable because all the input documents contain sliders and it's essential they're processed.

Comment: There is also other forEachs on the file that happen after with Regex and they work fine. Also as I said, this only happens with FS loaded files. The exact same file as a string works.

Comment: Not sure all the things you mean, exactly :) You will probably need to spell it out so someone can answer.